# WSO2ESB Twilio connector doesn't work behind proxy

Tags: proxy, wso2, twilio, wso2-esb

I tried using the Twilio connector for WSO2ESB behind a proxy, but I keep getting SocketTimeout exceptions. I tried setting the proxy in axis2.xml and through the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable, but nothing worked. As far as I can see, the Twilio connector either doesn't work behind a proxy, or it requires some special settings, since I can make REST calls to Twilio service via Call mediator, I just can't get the connector to work.

Comment: Can you please share your proxy service xml? Please see (http://wokis.blogspot.com/2016/05/send-sms-through-wso2-twilio-connector.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort parameters in axis2.xml to make esb to tunnel through proxy server.

Find more info with following link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Enabling+SSL+Tunneling+through+a+Proxy+Server